# Sharing 1 scrollbar between two DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, scroll

I am making a wpf application that has 2 datagrids and I want them to scroll together. 
I know that the DataGridView class has a scroll event that you can use make the necessary changes to the other grid, but DataGrids don't have a Scroll event. I MUST use a DataGrid.

This example is good but is not WPF and it's using DataGridView instead of DataGrid. [Using one scroll bar to control two DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229589/using-one-scroll-bar-to-control-two-datagridview)

What is the best way to have it so that one data grid's scroll bar also will move the data grid's scroll bar in WPF and DataGrids?

Comment: Here is a another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42046723/2431645

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by getting the underlying ScrollViewer of both DataGrid's and setting up the event accordingly. Below is a quick example I made that appears to work as you've described.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="52,69,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="270,69,0,0" Name="dataGrid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Person> _collection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        ScrollViewer scrollView = null;
        ScrollViewer scrollView2 = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                var p = new Person() { Name = string.Format("{0}", i), Age = i };
                _collection.Add(p);
            }
            this.DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void scrollView_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newOffset = e.VerticalOffset;

            if ((null != scrollView) && (null != scrollView2))
            {
                scrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset);
                scrollView2.ScrollToVerticalOffset(newOffset);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Person> Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return _collection;
            }
        }

        private ScrollViewer getScrollbar(DependencyObject dep)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dep); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dep, i);
                if ((null != child) && child is ScrollViewer)
                {
                    return (ScrollViewer)child;
                }
                else
                {
                    ScrollViewer sub = getScrollbar(child);
                    if (sub != null)
                    {
                        return sub;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            scrollView = getScrollbar(dataGrid1);
            scrollView2 = getScrollbar(dataGrid2);

            if (null != scrollView)
            {
                scrollView.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scrollView_ScrollChanged);
            }
            if (null != scrollView2)
            {
                scrollView2.ScrollChanged += new ScrollChangedEventHandler(scrollView_ScrollChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is happening is that I'm iterating through the VisualTree of both DataGrids upon Window load using getScrollbar. I then set up the scroll changed event for both DataGrids and then scroll to the vertical offset that was just changed inside the scroll changed event handler.

Comment: Thank you so so much! I have been looking for 2 days now! I haven't tested your code with mine yet but this looks to be exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: I have my datagrids inside of a usercontrol. The usercontrol in the window is in an expander so I am trying to figure out how to use it with mine.

Comment: @Lainezor You should still be able to access the DataGrid's ScrollViewer using getScrollbar(datagridname). Run the sample stand-alone first, it might help you.

Comment: @moncada, instead of attaching the event handlers in the code-behind, why not do it in XAML?

Comment: @badmaash yeah, you definitely could. this was just a quick solution I came up with. I can post a XAML version when I get home from work.